# Alei Shur Online

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books, internet, mussar-ethics

Does anyone know if there is a copy of Rav Wolbe's Alei Shur anywhere online? Free versions preferred, but if it is behind a paywall that can work too.

Thanks!

Comment: There isn’t one, amd the family is unlikely to approve the project.

Comment: @Dr.Shmuel Volume 1

Comment: @MichaBerger you are very likely sadly correct :(

Comment: Copyright violation is both legally and halachically prohibited. So, no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. It's not on Otzar HaChochmah or HebrewBooks.

Comment: I'll accept this since my research leads me to believe so as well, but won't upvote since I don't follow the logic - there are many sefarim available online that are not on Hebrewbooks or Otzar HaChochma.

Comment: No problem. Rov HaSefarim online are available on Otzar HaChochmah, HebrewBooks, Bar Ilan, and Sefaria. If you use a different venue, I'd be interested in taking a look.

Comment: I completely agree with your comment. Firstly, you hadn't mentioned Bar Ilan and Sefaria.  Second of all, you didn't say most Sefarim. There are occasionally sefarim that are not found in any of those repositories that can be found on individual webpages, by searching Google books or scholar, etc.

Comment: Beseder. I didn't feel like I needed to mention Bar Ilan and Sefaria since they're mostly encompassed by the other two in terms of content. I assumed it was self understood that these are the repositories for most Sefarim, but thank you for asking me to clarify

Comment: I'm not aware of any sites that come close to Otzar HaChochmah and HebrewBooks in terms of sheer numbers.